# Is the following thing true?

Tags: rituals, animals, sacrifice

I have seen long before in one of Dhruv Rathe's video that there was one ritual before in which hindus were to kill buffalo just like in the movie bahubali. I guess the ritual was thread ceremony or I don't know. What is the truth about this. What is the truth behind hindus killing buffalo in a ritual in the past?

Comment: Who is Dhruv Rathe? a preacher on Hinduism?

Comment: @SK oh yes indeed. Thanks a lot